# Loop through result set of mysql in Bash - routines

Tags: mysql, bash

I want to make specific `.sql` file for each of my routines.

```
#!/bin/bash

 routine_names=$(mysql mydb  --execute="SELECT 
    *
FROM
    information_schema.routines
WHERE
    routine_type = 'PROCEDURE' OR routine_type ='FUNCTION'
        AND routine_schema = 'mydb';"|cut -f1)

for routine in "$routine_names"
do
    if [ -e "${routine}.sql" ]
     then
    echo "ok"
    else
     content_procedure=$(mysql mydb--execute="SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE $routine;")
     echo "$content_procedure" >> masoud.txt
   fi   
done
```

my `routine_names` variable is a list of my procedures. like this:

```
SP_ONE
SP_TWO
SP_THREE
```

I want to loop of these result. but I think the result is not an array. because `routine` variable has all content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your `mysql mydb ...` command with `()`

```
 routine_names=($(mysql mydb  --execute="SELECT 
    *
FROM
    information_schema.routines
WHERE
    routine_type = 'PROCEDURE' OR routine_type ='FUNCTION'
        AND routine_schema = 'mydb';"|cut -f1))
```

I was curious and got the idea from [here](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/148102-cut-f1-d-array-loop.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just another case how I fix my problem

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u USER -p -h localhost -D database1 -e "SELECT ID FROM prodTable WHERE display=1 AND new=1 AND exDate<DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)" | while read ID;
do 
      echo "The following product has been moved: $ID"
done
```